# Is it possible to become pregnant indirectly?

Tags: pregnancy

Is it possible to become pregnant indirectly? For instance, if there is some wet semen left behind inside tight clothing, jeans for example, and a woman tries them on for a couple of minutes? What is sperm's motility after it's deposited on cloth in room temperature? Can sperm still swim inside from outside if it's near the vaginal opening in the cloth? What are the chances of pregnancy if the woman is/is not wearing any underwear?

Comment: Good question but poorly narrated. Refine your question by reducing questions to just single one. It's sounding pretty curious but snappy question. Once refined, it will be very good question

Answer (score -1):

yes this is possible, as long as the sperm make it onto the mucus membrane of the vagina. the LIKELYHOOD depends on the fabric and how much semen is in the fabric, if it's still clotted or not, and environmental factors.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I meant liquefied semen on the cloth so that it appears as a wet spot, the kind of semen smudge you get when it has seeped through thin clothing (underwear) before being deposited on that outer layer (jeans).

Comment: if youre being that specific, it probably happened to you. take a pregnancy test. if positive, there is sadly not much you can do except murder the unborn child. his body your choice